# Is that possible to connect Ubuntu HDFS using C# application

Tags: hadoop

I am having HDFS in Ubuntu Environment, Is that possible to connect Ubuntu HDFS using C# application (Windows OS).

All the systems are connected via LAN.

I want to read simple CSV file from HDFS.

I want to know whether it is possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Hortonworks Azure HDInsight you can directly use C# to access the HDFS. In your case you are trying to read from windows OS. Please try using webhdfs. But it need configuration. Please check the below url for details.

URL: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/

Comment: Thanks your post give me a correct path of my requirement, I have CDH 5.4.4 version by default it contains httpfs with username as **hue**